# New feature when asking a new question: drag & drop for suggested tags or clicking on it adds it to the tags

Tags: feature-request

It would be a nice feature, if you could make suggested tags (when asking a new question) clickable.

When clicking on the suggested tags, it is added to the tags section of the question or at least you can drag and drop it in the tags sections.

[image: Suggested tags]

Comment: Doesn't this exist? In my experience they are clickable.

Comment: They are clickable but when you click you display more details about the tag. We can move this behavior to hover instead.